Forms authentication failed for the request. ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
I have a SOAP webservice which integrates an ecommerce platform and my ERP. From time to time I see an authentication failed error on the web store and the store completely stops working.
The webstore is making the below request:
Request information: 
    Request URL: https://b1webapi.internal.ptlone.com:443/GNL_BRANDS_INTL_TEST/query/saltbox/GetWorkFlowMessages.aspx?B1ObjectType=14&b1TransactionType=Exclude&Tag=Shopify&PageNum=1&PageSize=-1 
    Request path: /GNL_BRANDS_INTL_TEST/query/saltbox/GetWorkFlowMessages.aspx 
    User host address: 34.196.190.164 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

and I found the event logged in the event viewer on the server where the webservice is.
Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. 
Event time: 5/1/2024 11:16:47 AM 
Event time (UTC): 5/1/2024 3:16:47 PM 
Event ID: bf382d55c867472fbdb67dc305cd7503 
Event sequence: 404 
Event occurrence: 403 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-1-133590267234662286 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\zedIT\zed B1WebAPI\ 
    Machine name: PTLONE-WEB 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 6712 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: https://b1webapi.internal.ptlone.com:443/GNL_BRANDS_INTL_TEST/query/saltbox/GetWorkFlowMessages.aspx?B1ObjectType=14&b1TransactionType=Exclude&Tag=Shopify&PageNum=1&PageSize=-1 
    Request path: /GNL_BRANDS_INTL_TEST/query/saltbox/GetWorkFlowMessages.aspx 
    User host address: 34.196.190.164 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
 
Name to authenticate: admin 

In addition to this I see when this happens w3wp.exe process for this particular webservice has zero network activity on the resource monitor.
Has anyone faced a similar incident. What are my further troubleshooting options? Thanks for your help.
